# Is it appropriate to use AJAX to render index.js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm a little bit confused about the appropriateness of using AJAX to render a page. First, I'll explain what I'm trying to do and then explain my logic.

I have a task list rails app that I'm making. Upon creation of a task, I want the created task to be displayed on the index page with a color code based upon its priority. A task with High would be red, a task with Medium would be orange and Low would be green. To do this, I know that I need jQuery to add a .css or addClass method but I'm confused as to how to do this. In a previous question user meager told me that I needed to serve the information form the controller to my priority.js.erb file which includes this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if (<% @task.importance == "Low" %>) {
      $("td").addClass("green");
    } else if(<% @task.importance == "Medium" %>) {
      $("td").addClass("orange");
    } else {
      $("td").addClass("red");
    }
  });
```

I understand that the controller needs to serve it because my priority.js.erb file breaks because @task doesn't exist. But here's the thing that I don't get. How do I implement doing this and what files do I need. I understand that AJAX is used typically for features that don't require a page refresh like commenting on a blog and things like that, but what I want DOES require a page refresh. I need someone to click on new.html.erb, create a task which goes to my controller, does something like this:

```
def create
@task = Task.new(task_params)
respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to tasks_path, notice: "Task created!"
    end

    format.json do
      render json: @task
    end
  end
end
```

and then refresh the index.html page. Would I need a separate index.js.erb file that does this?

Or am I completely wrong about using AJAX? Do I even need to use it? I'm just terribly confused because I'm not exactly sure what needs to be done. If you guys need to elaborate more or provide some more information let me know and I'll edit the question. I really want to make this feature work. Thx.

Comment: Quick question: are you using a remote call to create the task or are you submitting the task form back to the controller via the normal request-response cycle? In other words, what steps do you employ to create a new task?

Comment: I don't know what a remote call is but I'm assuming its the regular request-response cycle. There is a form on my new.html.erb page that sends the info to the controller, the only thing I want in between the response and the rendering is to add the jQuery to the newly created task.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any AJAX for this what-so-ever. As you mentioned in your comments above, your `new` form is posting the task information to the create method inside the TasksController.

In your TasksController `create` method:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  if @task.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          redirect_to tasks_path, notice: "Task created!"
        end
        # you probably don't need this, at this time (but it doesn't hurt)
        format.json do 
          render json: @task
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Be sure to save the task with `@task.save` as it was missing from your controller code in the original post.

Then, in your TasksController `index` view (`app/views/tasks/index.html.haml` or `app/views/tasks/index.html.erb`), you can do something like this (using HAML as my view language):

```
- @tasks.each do |task|
  - case task.importance.titleize
  - when 'Low'
    %tr.green
  - when 'High'
    %tr.red
  # the above assumes you want to apply a background color to an entire table row
    %td= task.name (etc.)
```

In some stylesheet:

```
.green { background-color: #SOMEHEX; }
.red { background-color: #SOMEOTHERHEX; }
```

When your index page renders, displaying all requested tasks, your HAML or ERB index view will output a class on your table row based on the importance attribute on each task. By defining your classes in a stylesheet, the rows in your table will display in the correct color and such.

Since you are using the basic request-response approach in your web app, you do not *need* AJAX.

Hope that helps get you going!

Comment: this really helped alot. I was getting very confused with javascript and AJAX. Thanks a lot.